# How to Filter Data in Grid when Route Changed

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi I'm very new to angular.

I have an url like `http://localhost:3000/prizes/brand1` , brand2, brand3

I want to reload my grid items and filter them base on that brand.

```
{ path: 'prizes/:brand_name', component: PrizeComponent }
```

This is the method that I have to get the items

```
getPrizes() {
   return this._http.get('/prizes')
   .map(data => data.json()).toPromise()
 }
```

Question

How do I reload/call back the get method base on the new route and how do I get the brand name and pass that one as a parameter to the get method.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If to use dataService to fetch data:

```
@Injectable()
export class daraService {
 private brandName: string = '';

  constructor(aroute: ActivatedRoute) {
      aroute.url.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('params ', data); //check for brand here
         this.brandName = data[data.length - 1]
     });
   }

  getPrizes() {
    // you can access this.brandName value here
   return this._http.get('/prizes')
      .map(data => data.json()).toPromise()
   }
}
```